# Specifying slug in reverse order in Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

We have some namespaced controllers on our app.

It's pretty easy to do this:

```
/store/pants
/store/shirts/2
```

In a multi-tenant environment, we would like to do this:

```
/:tenant_slug/hats
/:tenant_slug/hats/3
/jims-discount-apparel/gloves
```

And have those routes map to the namespaced controllers:

```
Store::HatsController
Store::GlovesController
```

We **are not** going to use `/store/:tenant_slug/hats`

I want any route that starts with a :tenant_slug to be mapped to the appropriate controller in the `Store` namespace.

**We have several controllers under `Store` and would like to avoid listing them all (hats, gloves, shirts, pants, etc...) in `routes.rb`.**

I was trying to use `match` but I can't quite get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this not working?

`get '/:tenant_slug/hats', to: 'store/hats#index', as: 'hats'`

Should generate the following route, and params[:tenant_slug] will contain that part of the URI:

`hats GET    /:tenant_slug/hats(.:format)          store/hats#index`

Comment: That probably works but I'm trying to avoid listing all the possibilities (hats, gloves, shirts) in routes.rb

Comment: If you don't follow the Rails convention you will have to write them all by hand

Comment: Or an alternative would be to use sub-domain and :tenant_slug would be the sub-domain part before your domain name. It all depend on your app needs

Comment: Yeah that's our backup plan. Thanks!

Comment: How did you fix this finaly?

Comment: We never did. For now, living with `/:tenant_slug/store/:controller/:action'